# How can Select/Deselect and Enable/Disable status for a row in a table?

Tags: website-design, icons, disable

I have an web application that which after processing some files show at the user the result about this processing. Now the user can select one or more to save and at the same time he can enable or disable the rows. I think this is not user friendly and i want to change my approach. This is mockup about my table:

[image]

What's the correct way to manage this?

Comment: Why are there Checkboxes on the Right and Left of the Result? Are they related in any way?

Comment: The first one is used to select/deselect the row while the second one is used to enable/disable the row

Comment: So if I disable the row, will it still be saved?

Comment: No If I disable the row, I can't saved it

Comment: What is the purpose of a user disabling one or more rows? Is it an action you expect them to make often?

Comment: Disable should be an action that the users will do rarely

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- **Speed** – small checkboxes are not the best controls for the fast/frequent
  actions, according to Fitts's Law. It's too slow and exhausting to use chechboxes for the big data set
- **Errors** – placing checkboxes with different
  actions close to each other (Select and Disable) could cause errors
  (slips) while performing the action (e.g. clicking Disable instead of
  Select)
- **Feedback** – small checkbox area has poor visual sign of the item's
  status, it's better to have more prominent visual feedback
- Cancel button doesn't needed, use Reset or such instead to reset the items

Possible solution:

- The item is selected by clicking on the entire row to make selection more fast. All the row is highlighted
- Disable control is visible when mouse is over the appropriate row to reduce visual noize. Disabled items are faded

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I made on the commute.

[image: product results]

Reorganized the **Checkboxes to the left** to follow good principles.

Make sure you give a strong sense of **Select All** Checkboxes.

Place **Save nearer to the Checkboxes** so the user will be closer to it, plus show a positive color for the button.

**Cancel is a negative action** so can be a little less dominating.